# How can I transform my dataframe in something readable by a boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

```
        TEXT1   TEXT2   TEXT3   TEXT4
sample1   38     53      337     3995
sample2   54     81      532     4801
sample3   74     108     750     4921
sample4   103    155     1113    4923
```

This table shows four different texts, and a set of samples (processing time in seconds) for each one of them. I have some large datasheets with this kind of information (hundreds of samples for each text). I have this table loaded into a data frame, df.

My intention is to represent this in a boxplot with four boxes, one for each text. I can easily represent one box, with:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x="T1",y=TEXT1)) + geom_boxplot()
```

or, substituting TEXT1 with its value:

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x="T1",y=df[1:4,2])) + geom_boxplot()
```

but I am not able to plot all the four boxes, I have tried this (don't really mind the values for the x scale):

```
ggplot(data=df,aes(x=1:4,y=df[1:4,2:5])) + geom_boxplot()
```

but it says that arguments have different number of rows.

Looking at ohter examples I think that if I reshape my data frame so I have only two columns with a pair TEXTX | sample in each row, then I could assign the first column to the x coordinate and the second to the y coordinate, and it should produce the result I am looking for.

But I don't see an easy way to do that. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: You can reshape easily with the `melt` function in the reshape2 package, which is by the same author as ggplot2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very easy if you add the sample column and use it as the id variable:

```
df$sample<-rownames(df)
require(reshape2)
df2 = melt(df, id.vars="sample" )

# 1  sample1    TEXT1    38
# 2  sample2    TEXT1    54
# 3  sample3    TEXT1    74
# 4  sample4    TEXT1   103
# 5  sample1    TEXT2    53
# 6  sample2    TEXT2    81
# 7  sample3    TEXT2   108
# 8  sample4    TEXT2   155
# 9  sample1    TEXT3   337
# 10 sample2    TEXT3   532
# 11 sample3    TEXT3   750
# 12 sample4    TEXT3  1113
# 13 sample1    TEXT4  3995
# 14 sample2    TEXT4  4801
# 15 sample3    TEXT4  4921
# 16 sample4    TEXT4  4923
```

and plot with

```
ggplot(df2,aes(x=sample,y=value)) + geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Finally I did: newdata <- melt(df[1:4,2:5], X=c("TEXT1","TEXT2","TEXT3","TEXT4"))